# spring cloud zuul + multiple ui bundles + angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring, cloud, netflix-zuul

I have  multiple UI bundles.

My zuul yml entry

server
 port : 8090

zuul:
  routes:
    ui:
      url: http://localhost:8091
      sensitive-headers:

When i try to hit url http://localhost:8090/ui
it loaded my html code but not include js and css file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely your href tags are not properly linked

Comment: I am hitting on browser directly, when  i put
zuul.routes.tg.path=/**
zuul.routes.tg.url=http://localhost:8091

Then its working and loading all js and css but when i put

zuul.routes.tg.path=/resource/**
zuul.routes.tg.url=http://localhost:8091

it loaded html code but not js and css

Answer (score 1):

I would want to have a closer look at the HTML that is returned when you go to the http://localhost:8090/ui. Or at least use Chrome developer tools to see what URL it is using when trying to load the JS and CSS. I had a similar issue with how Zuul does the routing. It is not a full reverse proxy in that it doesn't inspect the HTML body of the response to modify embedded URLs to be corrected.

Check out: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/8

Comment: it search js on this location http://localhost:8090/data/js/controller.js   and coundnt find because my js is on 8091 server

Comment: You need to setup Zuul to have routes for /data to point at the backend service. The good thing is you have relative URLs for your resources on the page. As such you just need to setup the route and the page should be able to load it.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I did change is my zuul yml with respect to my resources and now its working as per requirement.

Comment: Can you guys show me how to do that please? because I'm having the same trouble and I'm stuck with that.